# error installing iproute2

Tags: iptables

I was trying to install iproute2 on my ubuntu 16.04.1 and when I tried to ./configure I am getting the following error.

```
TC schedulers
 ATM    no
 IPT    using xtables
 IPSET  yes
iptables modules directory: /lib/xtables
libc has setns: yes
SELinux support: no
ELF support: no
libmnl support: no
Berkeley DB: no

docs: latex: no
 WARNING: no docs can be built from LaTeX files

 sgml2html: no
 WARNING: no HTML docs can be built from SGML
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there's a reason to build from source, you should take the easy way:

```
apt-cache search iproute2
```

and then,

```
sudo apt-get install iproute2 iproute2-doc
```

Or, you could read the `README*` files that came with the source, and add parameters to your `./configure`.